# Passing List<T> from View to Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm stuck on an issue passing a List of type T from a view back to a controller that loads the list in a partial view to display them in a modal dialog.

Here's what I have:

View passing to Controller:

```
@foreach(var queue in itemQueues)
{
    <td>@Html.ActionLink(queues.OpenItems.Count.ToString(), "ItemQueueDetails", "Pod", new { collection = queue.OpenItems }, null)</td>
}
```

Controller passing to partial view:

```
public ActionResult ItemQueueDetails(List<Item> collection)
{
    var cols = typeof(Incident).GetProperties();
    ViewData["DataHeaders"] = cols;
    ViewData["DataRows"] = collection;

    return PartialView("QueueDetails");
}
```

The partial view does what you'd expect so I don't really think it's pertinent right now.

The only problem is that the collection parameter always ends up with a List with zero elements, regardless of how many elements are stored in the queue list that is passed as an argument to the ItemQueueDetails ActionResult.

My application only displays data.  The initial view simply shows counts of queues (although it is passed the entire list and simply displays the count) while clicking on the # of items is supposed to display the modal that shows the actual details.

Comment: Did you try using `ViewBag` instead?

Comment: @abatishchev My understanding was that the ViewBag allowed passing data from the controller to the view, and not the other way around.  I need to pass my List from a view to a controller.

Comment: A view isn't supposed to send anything back to the controller in such manner in first place. Try to rethink/redesign.

Comment: Also try add another partial view, don't reuse the first one.

Comment: Since you already have the data when rendering the main view, is there a reason you are not just including the details in the main view (perhaps in a hidden element and toggling its visibility)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `Viewbag` or `ViewData` or `TempData` and Put list inside it and then again put it inside `ViewData["DataRows"]` in controller action  or try something like this :-

```
 @foreach(var queue in itemQueues)
  {
     <td>
        @Html.ActionLink(queues.OpenItems.Count.ToString(), "ItemQueueDetails",
        "Pod", new RouteValueDictionary{
        { "collection[0]", queue.OpenItems[0] },
        { "collection[1]", queue.OpenItems[1] }
        })
     </td>
  }
```

Comment: Yeah. In other words, you're screwed. MVC.net was not designed to pass objects, because HTTP was not designed to pass objects. At most it passes strings, which the server side then interprets as properties of an object. or a collection of strings, which can then be interpreted as a property of a collection. But that's just plain ugly programming.